# Regex on Dataframe Values

Tags: python, regex

```
def Clean_Data(df):
   df.replace({ r'\A\s+|\s+\Z': '', '\n' : ' ', '\w\s+\w|\w\n\w': '\w\s\w'}, regex=True, inplace=True)
   return df
```

I would like to clean my dataframe before I work on it. 
I need to get rid of:

double whitespace

whitespace + linebreak

-> and replace it with a single whitespace.

As well I want to check if there is more than one whitespace between two words (letters or numbers) and reduce it to a single whitespace.

And at least Check if there ae whitespaces between words and signs (, or .) and replace with ''.

But I have literally no idea of regex and getting already an error for `bad escape \w`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this
`df.replace({' +':' ', '\n':' ','->':' '}, regex=True, inplace=True)`

First one checks for more than one whitespaces and replaces with only one whitespace.
Second one checks for new line and replaces with white space
Third is the pattern -> and replaces with white space